# Access first row in table

Tags: html, css

I have HTML table in my webPage. I have applied css to that table.
now i want to change css only for first Row that is Table header.

i dont have th in table header, because the table is autogenerated from gridView

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: I don't know gridView, but [surely it can insert a header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerrow.aspx) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tr:first-child
```

Apply styles to that.

Comment: That will match the first table row in the table header AND the table footer AND each table body.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using CSS pseudo class `:first-child`

Read this for details: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Better solution. I always encourage the use of `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. You should mention `:first-child` pseudo class isn't always supported (IE)

Answer (score 2):

If by "gridView" you're refering to the [ASP.NET GridView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), you can use the [ShowHeader property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheader.aspx) to have a `th` generated.

This will then allow you to hook into the `th` and will be more semantcially correct.

```
myGridControl.ShowHeader = true;
```

or

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeader="true" [...]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS pseudo class `:first-child`, for example:

```
table tbody tr:first-child
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KvHsb/